# Joining two arrays using a common property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What I want to do is basically join the information from two arrays via `userId`. Until then, this solution that I made works only when there is little data, if they are very large arrays, this huge amount of `filter` is very impractical. Can anyone think of a more efficient solution?

**PS: I'm using > 0 ? because sometimes one of the properties is empty.**

```
const data01 = [
      { userId: 0, motorcycles: 'motorcycle01', cars: 'car01' },
      { userId: 1, motorcycles: 'motorcycle02', cars: 'car02' },
      { userId: 2, cars: 'car03' },
      { userId: 3, motorcycles: 'motorcycle04' },
    ]


    items.forEach(
      a =>
      (
        a.motorcylces = data01.filter(b => b.userId === a.userId).length > 0 ? data01.filter(b => b.userId === a.userId)[0].motorcylces : null,
        a.cars = data01.filter(b => b.userId === a.userId).length > 0 ? data01.filter(b => b.userId === a.userId)[0].cars : null
      )
    );

    console.log(items)
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
       ...
       motorcycles: 'motorcycle01',
       cars: 'cars01'
    },
    {
       ...
       motorcycles: 'motorcycle01',
       cars: 'cars01'
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample output? Also which one is the 2nd array ?

Comment: Why are you using the comma operator here? Just use an ordinary function body with two assignments.

Comment: @Dharmaraj done!

Comment: @Barmar I believe the code gets cleaner

Comment: Your desired result looks like the original `data01`

Comment: What is in `items`?

Comment: BTW, you misspelled `motorcycles`

Comment: Items is another generic array with other properties. What I want is to add some properties (motocycles and cars) to the items array.

Comment: You should be using `.find()` rather than `.filter()`, if you only want the first element that's found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up the process by creating a Map of `data01`, keyed by `userId`.

And with `Object.assign` you can copy the properties from a match. This will not create the property if it doesn't exist in the source, so there will be no `null` assignments (unless the source has an explicit `null`):

```
let map = new Map(data01.map(o => [o.userId, o]));
items.forEach(a => Object.assign(a, map.get(a.userId)));
```

If you are only interested in a selection of properties, then create objects that only have those properties:

```
let map = new Map(data01.map(o => 
    [o.userId, { cars: o.cars, motorcycles: o.motorcycles }]
));
items.forEach(a => Object.assign(a, map.get(a.userId)));
```

This second solution will always create the specific properties, also when they didn't exist yet. In that case their values will be `undefined`.

Comment: In this case I want to keep the properties of the "items" array and add the properties "motorcycles" and "cars"

Comment: OK, so then go for the second variant in my answer. But also the first keeps the properties of the items array. It just doesn't always add the "motorcycles" and "cars" properties -- when they don't exist in `data01`.

Comment: Even with this optimization it takes more than 5 seconds to merge the data : / But your answer was good.

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are arrays of objects, and you need to consolidate 2+ arrays based on some property in the object, seems like the best thing to do would be to make an intermediate map that has its keys as the userIDs, and then just code something that will non-destructively update the map as you iterate through the arrays.

```js
const data01 = [
      { userId: 0, motocycles: 'motocycle01', cars: 'car01' },
      { userId: 1, motocycles: 'motocycle02', cars: 'car02' },
      { userId: 2, cars: 'car03' },
      { userId: 3, motocycles: 'motocycle04' },
    ]

const data02 = [
      { userId: 0, dogs: 'doggy', cats: 'car01' },
      { userId: 1, dogs: 'doggo', cats: 'car02' },
      { userId: 2, dogs: 'sheperd' },
      { userId: 3, cats: 'kitty' },
    ]


function combineArrFromUserId(arr1,arr2){
  const idMap= new Map()
  data01.forEach(item=>checkAndAdd(item,idMap))
  data02.forEach(item=>checkAndAdd(item,idMap))
  return idMap.values()
}

function checkAndAdd(item,map){
  const current =  map.get(item.userId)
  if(current){
    map.set(item.userId,Object.assign(current,item))
  } else {
    map.set(item.userId, item)
  }
}

console.log(combineArrFromUserId(data01,data02))
```